# Unselect multiple values in Filter

Tags: excel, vba, macos, filter

I want vba to unselect the the give colour from the column filter

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AK$10000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>red", Operator:=xlOr, _
    Criteria2:="<>Blue", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:="<>pink", _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Are you sure that the above code works as it is? You cannot have more than two criteria of "does not equal" type. In such a case you can build an array of **all the other colors** and filter by it. Then, using `xlOr` as operator, no filter will be applied, I am afraid. Now, how do you want 'telling' to VBA to unselect a specific such string color name? I mean, how to **give** it...

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code. It will elimnate one from the three mentioned colors (if you write it in `InputBox`. If nothing is written there, the filter will be configured to use (exclude) all three (pink, blue, red):

```
Sub ExcludeFilterCondition()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRK As Long, arrInit, arrK, exclCol As String
 Dim mtch, i As Long, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
 lastRK = sh.Range("K" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row

 arrInit = Split("red,blue,pink", ",")
 exclCol = InputBox("Please, write a color name to be excluded from the filter criteria", "Exclude one color")

 If exclCol <> "" Then arrInit = filter(arrInit, exclCol, False)

 arrK = sh.Range("K2:K" & lastRK).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrK)                             'place in the array to be used as criteria only colors not existing in arrInit
    mtch = Application.match(arrK(i, 1), arrInit, 0)
    If IsError(mtch) Then
        dict(arrK(i, 1)) = vbNullString
    End If
 Next i

 'Place the filter for all existing colors, EXCEPT the ones in (processed) arrInit:
 sh.Range("$A$1:$K$100").AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:=dict.Keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

As I said in my comment, your code as you show could not work, from two reasons.

1. No more than two conditions of **"does not equal" type** are allowed;
2. Even using it for two (allowed) conditions, `xlOr` operator excludes each other...

Comment: @Farooq Didn't you find some time to test the above solution? If tested, didn't it do what you need?